# Liferay Control Panel Layout

Tags: eclipse, liferay-6, liferay-ide

I have installed Liferay Portal on Jelastic.
I need to install the Remote IDE Connector to deploy my project in remote with eclipse.
My problem is that, in my remote Liferay Portal, the control pannel is different: there is not the marketplace menu where I will want install the Remote IDE Connector.

Why? Can somebody help me, please?

Answer (score 0):

MarketPlace Portlet was enforced from Liferay Portal 6.1 CE GA2+. Just see whther there are any version differences between your and the Remote.

You can get the marketplace portlet in .war format and hot deploy to make it same as your Control Panel.

Comment: How can I hot deploy? In Jelastic there is not the "deploy" folder